# Measuring Enzyme Kinetic constants

Tags: enzyme-kinetics

Is it possible to experimentally determine $k_1$ and $k_{-1}$ of the Michaelis Menten model:

$\ce{E + S <-->[k_1][k_{-1}] ES ->[k_{cat}] E + P}$,

or their ratio?